# Upgrading CPUs for my HP G5 DL380 - will the cooling suffice?

Tags: hp, central-processing-unit, upgrade, xeon, cooling

Just a month ago or so, I bought my first rack server for some personal number crunching. It's been great fun playing around with and I'm thinking about upgrading the CPUs to get more bang for the bucks ( and noise, lol ).

Is it likely that my current heat sinks for my 2 x 5160 CPUs will be good enough for quad cores from 54?? series? I guess it will be unlikely that the same cooling will work for the 120 watt models x5450-x5470, but maybe it would work with two e5450 which claim to use 80 watts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing you can do is buy the actual CPU kits packaged by HP for this server. But the heatsinks are likely similar.

`Quad-Core Intel® Xeon® Processor E5450 (3.0 GHz, 80 Watts, 1333 FSB) - 458583-B21`

Buy the entire kit (part #458583-B21). [See eBay pricing](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2060353.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.X458583-B21.TRS0&_nkw=458583-B21&_sacat=0).

The only problem is that the cost of this old CPU is high. It's cheaper to buy an entire new server with the [same CPUs already inside of it](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=e5450%20dl380&_sop=15).